# Django admin edit integer field

Tags: python, django

I have a model with two integer fields which are supposed to be foreign keys. In my admin view, those two fields are editable but I would like to display a search icon next to the field, so I can retrieve the id of another model and append to the field. Does django have this feature?

```
class Linkage(models.Model):

     user_id = models.IntegerField(default=1)
     parent_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: Why are you using an integer field rather than using a Foreign Key? Using a Foreign Key provides this functionality.

Comment: Yes it was done by mistake. If I change the integer field to foreign key. Would that cause issues?

Comment: Is this a new project? If you already have relationships, then you can either write complex migrations, or go about the process just changing it and going into the admin panel and manually assigning the relationships.

Comment: did my answer solve your problem? If not let me know so I can help you more

Answer (score 0):

If your model has 2 fields that should actually be foreign keys, then you need to use `ForeignKey` instead of `IntegerField`  as so:

```
from django.db import Models
from app.models import yourModel

class Linkage(models.Model):

     user_id = models.ForeignKey(yourModel)
     parent_id = models.ForeignKey(yourModel)
```

This Django feature will take care of linking your Linkage to your other model of choice automatically. In the admin, you will no longer need to set an integer with the id of the foreign key, you will be able to simply select an instance of the linked model.

You can read more about Django fields references [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).

---

*EDIT:* In the way you designed yoour models, there might for example not be a parent_id, so you can add options such as `null=True` to the `parent_id` field as so:

```
parent_id = models.ForeignKey(yourModel, null=True)
```

I strongly recommend that you read the Django documentation, it is really good for beginners as it is very detailed and clear. You can access the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/).
They also have a set of tutorials to get you through the steps and introduce you to the different basics you need to know to get started with Django [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/).

Comment: But there are certain parent_id which are 0, which means certain user do not have a parent on top of it. Would that be an issue?

Comment: @ping you can add more options. For example if there might be no `parent_id` then you will want to add the option `null=True` to your `parent_id`. Have a look at the link I attached in the answer, it links to the official Django documentation, which is really good and clear.